# How to debug stored procedure in ss2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Is there any way to debug stored procedure in Sql Server 2005 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL 2005 has no equivalent of the debugger found in SQL 2008.

To debug stored procedures in 2005 and earlier, the only method available is to either create a debug version by adding `PRINT` and `SELECT` statements at important points in the code, or to do the same thing whilst running the procedure's body code outside a procedure.

Comment: :thanks for reply.we can steps into the procedure but this is the hard coding in the sp and if our procedure uses contain large amount of data then it is tedious job to find out the required values.How ever i found another solution we can use visual studio to debug those.Here is the link (http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article27.aspx)

Comment: @RajaramShelar - I don't believe this will work with SQL 2005 - however please add your own answer if it does

Comment: @RajaramShelar - please add this solution as an answer to the question and accept it so that other users of the site can find it.